# framework7 with vuejs using axios

Tags: html, vue.js, axios, html-framework-7

I am new to framework7 and vuejs. Is this the correct way of importing it? After this, how can I reference the axios from other pages?

Below is my main.js and I'm not sure if it's being import correctly or am I missing some steps?

```
// Import Vue
import Vue from 'vue'

// Import F7
import Framework7 from 'framework7'

// Import F7 Vue Plugin
import Framework7Vue from 'framework7-vue'

// Import Routes
import Routes from './routes.js'

// Import Vue Resource for http .... not recommended anymore
//import VueResource from './vue-resource.js'

//http requests and other stuff
import Axios from './axios.min.js'

// Import App Component
import App from './app.vue'

// Init F7 Vue Plugin
Vue.use(Framework7Vue)

// Init App
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<app/>',
  // Init Framework7 by passing parameters here
  framework7: {
    root: '#app',
    /* Uncomment to enable Material theme: */
    // material: true,
    routes: Routes
  },
  // Register App Component
  components: {
    app: App
  },
  //methods
  methods: {

    getAppName: function () {
      console.log(this.appName)
    },

    msgBox: function () {
      alert('Message Box');
    },

    calNum: function () {
      alert(3 + 5);
    }

  }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 major ways you can do this.

1 (Preferred) import axios in any module using it

The standard way is to import axios in any module that needs it. for example in `test.vue`

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    mounted: function() {
        axios.get(....)
```

2 (I do this myself) Import once and make it global

This is simpler and by doing it once you dont need to do it every time in all modules.

a. import axios in `main.js`

b. make it global with this

```
window.axios = axios;
```

after this line everywhere in your code you have access to axios variable and can work with it

(Edit)

Actually now i saw that you import axios from file. It is preferred to do it with npm.

a. run this in command line in your project folder

```
npm install --save axios
```

b. change your import to this

```
import Axios from 'axios'
```

Comment: if this solved your issue can you mark this as answer?